# How do you find deprecated methods in a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm seeing blog posts where people mention deprecated methods in rails3, for example `model.errors.on is deprecated in favor of model.errors[]`

My question is, how do you find these deprecated methods? Is there a rake task or something I can run to find them in my project? Do I just need to look them up on a resource like [rails3 release notes](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/3_0_release_notes.html)? Or is there some other way?

Comment: I think they show up in the development log too.

Comment: Heikki, this is the answer I was looking for. If you add it as an answer I can give you credit for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Warnings surely show up in development.log :) BTW, i was asking to myself this question some days ago and i used a very brutal method. Having rails source on my laptop, i searched for all calls to the warn method. Brutal but efficient.